# Que version del Crystal Report es para Visual Net 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013

Buen dia Expertos, estoy programando en VisuaStudio.Net 2012  y Sqlserver 2012...

instale a 4 pc un programa todo corre perfecto ellos pueden cotizar y este se guarda en un pdf en una carpeta predeterminada, el error me ocurre después cuando instale en la 5 pc, 6 pc ,7 pc y 8 pc ,... lo que me imagino es que solo soporta para 4 pc o algo paso con el crystal report , porque desde la 5,6,7 y 8 pcs que fueron las ultimas que instale este programa me sale este error(aunque la cotización graba normal lo que pasa es que no esta generando el reporte.."el PDF" )  , en las 4 primeras pcs instaladas corre normal graba y crea su PDF .... les envio la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instalaste los ultimos service packs??
Si no es así puedes descargarlos [AQUÍ](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/06/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio-updates-runtime-downloads/)

Comment: amigo gabriel, al inicio tenia el crystal report versio: CRforVS_13_0_4 ... me salia algunos errores al exportar a una carpeta definida entonces instale el CRforVS_13_0_10, con esto me ejecuto bien comense a instalar en 4 maquinas como lo comente pero en la 5 maquina que instale comenso a salir este error pensque era problema del framework pero instale en otras maquinas igual me sale este mensaje solo en las primera 4 pcs funciona perfecto.